# How do I add authentication to my UserList?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new to java and I'm working on a typical notepad program that lets you save, edit, delete, and create notes. For the app I am trying to add authentication to my login page. I am having trouble with the initialization of the UserList. What exactly am I doing wrong ? Pretty sure this is a syntax problem, that I'm too oblivious to see right now

**UserList.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class UserList {

    //Declares 2 arraylists, one for the list of usernames and one for passwords
    private ArrayList<String> validUsernames;
    private ArrayList<String> validPasswords;
    private UserList theUserList;

    //Constructor that adds usernames and passwords to the arraylists
    public UserList() {

        validUsernames = new ArrayList();
        validPasswords = new ArrayList();

        validUsernames.add("");
        validUsernames.add("");
        validUsernames.add("");
        validUsernames.add("");
        validUsernames.add("");
        validPasswords.add("");
        validPasswords.add("");
        validPasswords.add("");
        validPasswords.add("");
        validPasswords.add("");
    }

    //Returns arraylist of valid users
    public ArrayList<String> getValidUsernames() {
        return validUsernames;
    }

    //Returns arraylist of valid passwords
    public ArrayList<String> getValidPasswords() {
        return validPasswords;
    }
}
```

**LoginCntl 
(authenticate method)**

```
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password){

        validUsernames = new ArrayList();
        **validUsernames = theUserList.getValidUsernames();** [line 42]

        validPasswords = new ArrayList();
        validPasswords = theUserList.getValidPasswords();
        for (int i = 0; i < validUsernames.size(); i++) {
            if (validUsernames.get(i).equals(username) && validPasswords.get(i).equals(password)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        theLoginUI.password.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? and if so, what error is it?

Comment: First of all, don't know why you add "" in the arrays. And if you have a trouble, please be more specific and tell us what exactly is going on in order to help you.

Comment: Yes I do get an error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at swagpad.LoginCntl.authenticate(LoginCntl.java:42)
 at swagpad.LoginUI$SubmitListener.actionPerformed(LoginUI.java:72)

Comment: Your error happens at line 42 in your `LoginCntl.java` file. Can you please post your `authenticate` method from that file and tell us which line is line 42?

Comment: I added the whole method and showed where line 42 is

Comment: why do you need 2 arrayLists?
my advice would be to use a HashMap
example:
HashMap<String,String> validUsers = new HashMap<>();
validUsers.put("user1","password1);
validUsers.put("user2","password2");
easier to use and better coupled username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
validUsernames = theUserList.getValidUsernames();
```

The only thing which can cause a `NullPointerException` on this line is if `theUserList` is null. 
Make sure you initialize `theUserList` *before* you try to access it. In this case before you call authenticate. Eg. you can initialize it when you declare it,  like this:

```
UserList theUserList = new UserList();
```

or else you have to check for null before trying to access it and do something appropriate in that situation. Eg

```
if(theUserList == null) {
    // do something about it
}
validUsernames = new ArrayList();
validUsernames = theUserList.getValidUsernames();
...
```